# Maximum call stack size exceeded for large iterators

Tags: javascript, iterator, v8, iterable, callstack

I'm trying to convert an iterator to an array. The iterator is the result of calling `matchAll` on a very long string. The iterator (I assume) has many matches within the string. First I tried it with the spread operator:

```
const array = [...myLongString.matchAll(/myregex/g)];
```

This gave me the error: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

So I tried iterating via `next()`:

```
const safeIteratorToArray = (iterator) => {
    const result = [];
    let item = iterator.next();

    while (!item.done) {
        result.push(item.value);
        item = iterator.next();
    }

    return result;
};
```

But this gives me the same error, on the `item = iterator.next()` line. So I tried making it async in an effort to reset the call stack:

```
const safeIteratorToArray = async (iterator) => {
    const result = [];
    let item = iterator.next();

    while (!item.done) {
        result.push(item.value);
        item = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(iterator.next())));
    }

    return result;
};
```

But I still get the same error.

If you are curious about the actual use case:

The regex I'm actually using is:

```
 /\[(.+?)\] \[DEBUG\] \[Item (.+?)\] Success with response: ((.|\n)+?)\n\[/g
```

And the contents of the text file (it's a log file) generally looks like:

```
[TIMESTAMP] [LOG_LEVEL] [Item ITEM_ID] Success with response: {
    ...put a giant json object here
}
```

Repeat that ad-nauseam with newlines in between each log.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `myLongString` or a subset of what is in there?  How long are these strings?

Comment: @mrrogers the string is the contents of a text file that is anywhere from 50mb - 300mb. The content being matched is a several-thousand-line json object (with newlines, indentation). So the file is comprised of many of these json objects. The code works fine when the file is on the smaller size but starts throwing errors when it gets closer to 300mb.

Comment: Got it.  Yeah - those are big strings.   Have you tried `Array.from(str.matchAll())`? Might be the same result if under the hood they're all doing the same thing.  It's possible that you just can't use `matchAll` with a string that large.  It likely depends a lot on the internals of that function.  Do you need `matchAll`?  I wonder if `match` would give you what you needed - and might lead to less recursion as `matchAll` returns an array of arrays.  Just throwing out some ideas.   :D

Comment: why you don't just convert it to json then match the fields?

Comment: @syduki Because it's a text file with more than just json objects printed in there. More specifically it's a log output file from a different process.

Comment: Also I do want to extract more than just the json objects. There's text that I want to map to the json object it's printed near.

Comment: Please provide enough information to make it reproducible. What is the regular expression?

Comment: @trincot Edited the post to add info

Comment: If the `next()` call throws, that sounds like a bug in the native `matchAll` implementation. What engine are you using? Build a [mcve] and report the issue in their bugtracker.

Comment: @Bergi node 16.5.0

Comment: @Infamous911 https://v8.dev/bugs

Comment: It seems it'd be better (using less CPU and RAM) to use a specialized tool like ripgrep `rg --json --multiline -e '(?s)\\[(.+?)\\] \\[DEBUG\\] \\[Item (.+?)\\] Success with response: (.*?\\n})'` via [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) and dissect it's output. Think of `subprocess.stdout.on('data', collectWholeEntryAndDissect)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

It's not about the iterator, it's about the RegExp.

**[Update]**
Looks like I was misled by a typo in my test, so my earlier explanation/suggestion doesn't fix the problem. With the test corrected, it turns out that *only* the end of the expression (which I called "fishy" before) needs to be fixed.

The massive consumption of stack memory is caused by the fact that `(.|\n)` is a capture group, and is matched very frequently. One idea would be to write it as `[.\n]` instead, but the `.` metacharacter is not valid inside `[...]` character sets.

Hat tip to @cachius for suggesting an elegant solution: use [the `s` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags) to make `.` match `\n` characters.
As an unrelated fix, prefer checking for the closing `}` instead of the next opening `[` at the beginning of a line, so that there's no overlap between matched ranges (which would make you miss some matches).
So, in summary, replace `((.|\n)+?)\n\[/g` with `(.+?)\n}/gs`.

[/Update]

Here is a reproducible example. The following exhibits the stack overflow:

```
let lines = ["[TIMESTAMP] [DEBUG] [Item ITEM_ID] {"];
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  lines.push("  [0]");  // Fake JSON, close enough for RegExp purposes.
}
lines.push("}");
lines.push("[TIMESTAMP]");
let myLongString = lines.join("\n");

const re = /\[(.+?)\] \[DEBUG\] \[Item (.+?)\] ((.|\n)+?)\n\[/g;
myLongString.match(re);
```

If you replace the `const re = ...` line with:

```
const re = /\[(.+?)\] \[DEBUG\] \[Item (.+?)\] (.+?)\n}/gs;
```

then the stack overflow disappears.

(It would be possible to reduce the simplified example even further, but then the connection with your original case wouldn't be as obvious.)

[Original post below -- the mechanism I explained here is factually correct, and applying the suggested replacement indeed improves performance by 25% because it makes the RegExp simpler to match, it just isn't enough to fix the stack overflow.]
The problematic pattern is:

```
\[(.+?)\]
```

which, after all, means "a `[`, then any number of arbitrary characters, then a `]`". While I understand that regular expressions might *seem* like magic, they're actually real algorithmic work under the hood, kind of like miniature programs in their own right. In particular, any time a `]` is encountered in the string, the algorithm has to decide whether to count this as one of the "arbitrary characters", or as the one `]` that ends this sequence. Since it can't magically know that, it has to keep both possibilities "in mind" (=on the stack), pick one, and backtrack if that turns out to be incorrect. Since this backtracking information is kept on the stack (where else?), if you put sufficiently many `]` into your string, the stack will run out of space.

Luckily, the solution is simple: since what you actually mean is "a `[`, then any number of characters *that aren't `]`*, then a `]`", you can just tell the RegExp engine that, replacing `.` with `[^\]]`:

```
\[([^\]]+?)\]
```

Note: `((.|\n)+?)\n\[` seems fishy for the same reason, but according to this test doesn't appear to be the problem, even if I further increase the input size. I'm not sure why; it might be due to how I created the test. If you see further problems with the real input, it may be worth reformulating this part as well.
[/Original post]

Comment: As a V8 dev, what is your stance on using JS on 300mb strings?

Comment: @ReinState you gotta do what you gotta do, but regardless of programming language, processing huge strings in some sort of streaming/chunked fashion would likely be preferable (and certainly more scalable if your strings grow further in the future).

Comment: @jmrk This makes a lot of sense, thank you! I appreciate the RegExp lesson. One note is that I had to replace `\[([^]]+?)\]` with `\[([^\]]+?)\]` (escaping the bracket).

However, even with this I am still getting the stack overflow error occasionally. I think it is probably because of the `((.|\n)+?)\n\[` but I'm not sure how to reformulate that properly. It's tricky because it's not a single character that I don't want to match, but a sequence of two (newline followed by open square bracket). How should I approach this?

Comment: 1.) `(.|\n)`is a group that matches a single character but will never be used in any result. What you actually want is `.` to match the newline character. This can be enabled with [the flag `s`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags) at the end of the regex. 2.) By including the start of the next line `[` at the end of your regex, it cannot be matched against in the next regex iteration. With this regex you will miss lines. You need positive lookahead to prevent this. Or simpler switch to `(.+?\})\n` if possible.

Comment: @Infamous911 ha, good point about the missing `\]` escape; turns out that typo misled me in a big way and I have to change the meat of my explanation what's going on here. Updated the answer accordingly, and also worked in cachius' great suggestion.

Comment: @jmrk Your updated answer makes sense -- I'm using the new regex and able to avoid the stack overflow error now. I'll award you the bounty!

However, two points:
1. I found that the `[^\]]` switch for `.` made since to keep for two reasons: the `.` started giving me different results, potentially because of weirdness with the /s, but I'll have to look into it. And with `.` it was taking significantly longer to run (I think this makes sense based on your original explanation?)
2. Replacing `\[` at the end with `}` doesn't work because it then becomes invalid JSON. I solved it with `\n\n`.

Comment: @Infamous911 Re 1: Yes, as I wrote `[^\]]` will be faster, so I agree that keeping it makes sense; I dropped it from the new answer because it's not strictly required. Re 2: I see, you need the `}` as part of the capture group; you can also extend the capture group (i.e. move the closing ')') to achieve that: `(.+?\n})/gs`.